# Extracting specific string from a column content using Apache spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this column from my dataframe:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|          _classname                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|de.abs.org.vertrag.util.test.Elementofthetable                      |
|de.abs.org.vertrag.util.test.classes.Apachesparkproject             |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to get as expected dataframe:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|           _classname                                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|de.abs.org.vertrag.util.test                                        |
|de.abs.org.vertrag.util.test.classes                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to get rid of the classname of everypackage which is after the last (.)
here is my code :

```
teamNamesDf = teamNamesDf.select(col("_classname"), substring_index(col("_classname"), ".\\[^A-Z]+", -1).as("testSuiteName"));
```

This didnt work for me :( does anyone knows how to do that using Apache Spark Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex, which extracts everything before the final `.`:

```
Dataset<Row> result = df.select(regexp_extract(col("_classname"), "^(.*)\\.[^\\.]*$", 1))
```

Another way is to use `substring_index` with a variable length that depends on the number of `.` in the string:

```
Dataset<Row> result = df.selectExpr("substring_index(_classname, '.', size(split(_classname, '\\\\.')) - 1)")
```